# dimension of the subspace $W$ of $10\times 10$ matrices , $W=\{[a_{ij}]: a_{ij}=0\text{ if i is even }\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Could any one tell me how to find the dimension of the subspace $W$ of $10\times 10$ matrices , $W=\{[a_{ij}]: a_{ij}=0\text{ if i is even }\}$

from the given data I see that row  $2,4,6,8,10$ are $0$, and then  it becomes a $5\times 10$ matrix, so dimension $50$?
am I right?

Comment: To justify rigourously just exhibit a basis of your subspace, that should do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty in this question is to write one thing that is clear so let's do it even so. We know that the standard basis of $\mathcal M_{10}(\mathbb R)$ is $\mathcal B=(E_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq10}$ where $E_{ij}=(e_{pq})_{1\leq p,q\leq10}$ is the matrix defined by the Kronecker symbol $\delta$
$$e_{pq}=\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}$$
and for all matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in \mathcal M_{10}(\mathbb R)$ we have
$$A=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}a_{ij}E_{ij} $$
Now if $A\in W$ then
$$A=\sum_{\substack{i=1\\ i\ \text{ odd}}}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}a_{ij}E_{ij} $$
so $\mathcal B'=(E_{ij})_{\substack{i\in\{1,3,5,7,9\}\\1\leq j\leq10}}$ is basis for $W$ so $\dim W=50$.

Answer (score 1):

It does remain a $10 \times 10$ matrix, but because of all the zero rows, you can get away with $50$ independent "vectors" (which in this case are all matrices) to form a basis.  You have to be able to construct any given matrix from a linear combination of the basis vectors.  As suggested in the comments below, the basis should consist of 10x10 matrices each of which has a 1 in a cell which is or can be non-zero; and zeros elsewhere.

Comment: It is a subspace of the space of all $10\times 10$ matrices, under matrix addition. Such matrices can be thought of as vectors of length $100$, that happen to be arranged in rows of $10$. The subspace has dimension much larger than $5$. It is clearest to use a basis whose elements are $1$ in one place and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: You are right that the dimension is not 5, but using the basis you suggest, the dimension really 25.  You don't have to go out to 100, because 1/2 the rows are zero.

Comment: Yes, but each non-zero row has $10$ entries. A good basis is the $50$ matrices that are $0$ everywhere except for a $1$ in one of the $50$ possible positions in a non-zero row.

Comment: Yes, Andre, I just got back on to say that.  But you beat me to it.

Comment: @BettyMock Since you know that the answer is $5$ and not $50$, perhaps you could edit your answer?

Comment: Well, 50 and not 5, but thanks I did edit it.